# google fabric security announcements

Tags: security, fabric.io

Is there a security announcements channel somewhere for (Google) Fabric?
My question is triggered by a security requirement within my corporation to monitor all components that we use for security vulnerability announcements. Fabric is one of the components we use. I cannot find any security announcements channel so far, be it a mailing list or an RSS feed or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. If we needed to notify anyone due to a security issue, then we would send an email to the folks affected by it. You can also monitor our change logs: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/changelog.html and https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html

Comment: Thanks Mike. Good to hear that we will receive e-mail when such issues arise.